# strange chi-square result using scikit_learn with feature matrix

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn, chi-squared

I am using scikit learn to calculate the basic chi-square statistics(sklearn.feature_selection.chi2(X, y)):

```
def chi_square(feat,target):
"""   """
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
ch,pval =  chi2(feat,target)
return ch,pval



chisq,p = chi_square(feat_mat,target_sc)
print(chisq)
print("**********************")
print(p)
```

I have 1500 samples,45 features,4 classes. The input is a feature matrix with 1500x45 and a target array with 1500 components. The feature matrix is not sparse. When I run the program and I print the arrray "chisq" with 45 components, I can see that the component 13 has a negative value and p = 1. How is it possible? Or what does it mean or what is the big mistake that I am doing?

I am attaching the printouts of chisq and p:

```
[  9.17099260e-01   3.77439701e+00   5.35004211e+01   2.17843312e+03
   4.27047184e+04   2.23204883e+01   6.49985540e-01   2.02132664e-01
   1.57324454e-03   2.16322638e-01   1.85592258e+00   5.70455805e+00
   1.34911126e-02  -1.71834753e+01   1.05112366e+00   3.07383691e-01
   5.55694752e-02   7.52801686e-01   9.74807972e-01   9.30619466e-02
   4.52669897e-02   1.08348058e-01   9.88146259e-03   2.26292358e-01
   5.08579194e-02   4.46232554e-02   1.22740419e-02   6.84545170e-02
   6.71339545e-03   1.33252061e-02   1.69296016e-02   3.81318236e-02
   4.74945604e-02   1.59313146e-01   9.73037448e-03   9.95771327e-03
   6.93777954e-02   3.87738690e-02   1.53693158e-01   9.24603716e-04
   1.22473138e-01   2.73347277e-01   1.69060817e-02   1.10868365e-02
   8.62029628e+00]

**********************

[  8.21299526e-01   2.86878266e-01   1.43400668e-11   0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00   5.59436980e-05   8.84899894e-01   9.77244281e-01
   9.99983411e-01   9.74912223e-01   6.02841813e-01   1.26903019e-01
   9.99584918e-01   1.00000000e+00   7.88884155e-01   9.58633878e-01
   9.96573548e-01   8.60719653e-01   8.07347364e-01   9.92656816e-01
   9.97473024e-01   9.90817144e-01   9.99739526e-01   9.73237195e-01
   9.96995722e-01   9.97526259e-01   9.99639669e-01   9.95333185e-01
   9.99853998e-01   9.99592531e-01   9.99417113e-01   9.98042114e-01
   9.97286030e-01   9.83873717e-01   9.99745466e-01   9.99736512e-01
   9.95239765e-01   9.97992843e-01   9.84693908e-01   9.99992525e-01
   9.89010468e-01   9.64960636e-01   9.99418323e-01   9.99690553e-01
   3.47893682e-02]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put some print statements in [the code
defining](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_selection/univariate_selection.py#L138)
`chi2`,

```
def chi2(X, y):
    X = atleast2d_or_csr(X)
    Y = LabelBinarizer().fit_transform(y)
    if Y.shape[1] == 1:
        Y = np.append(1 - Y, Y, axis=1)
    observed = safe_sparse_dot(Y.T, X)          # n_classes * n_features
    print(repr(observed))
    feature_count = array2d(X.sum(axis=0))
    class_prob = array2d(Y.mean(axis=0))
    expected = safe_sparse_dot(class_prob.T, feature_count)
    print(repr(expected))
    return stats.chisquare(observed, expected)
```

you'll see that `expected` ends up having some negative
values.

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.feature_selection as FS

x = np.array([-0.23918515, -0.29967287, -0.33007592, 0.07383528, -0.09205183,
              -0.12548226, 0.04770942, -0.54318463, -0.16833203, -0.00332341,
              0.0179646, -0.0526383, 0.04288736, -0.27427317, -0.16136621,
              -0.09228812, -0.2255725, -0.03744027, 0.02953499, -0.17387492])

y = np.array([1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1],
             dtype = 'int64')

FS.chi2(x.reshape(-1,1),y)
```

yields

```
observed:
array([[-1.31238179],
       [-0.76922812],
       [-0.52522003]])

expected:
array([[-1.56409796],
       [-0.78204898],
       [-0.26068299]])
```

`stats.chisquared(observed, expected)` is then called. There, `observed`
and `expected` are assumed to be frequencies of categories. They should all be
non-negative numbers since frequencies are non-negative.

I'm not familiar enough with scikits-learn to suggest how your problem should be fixed, but it appears that the *kind* of data you are sending to `chi2` is of the wrong sort, since `expected` should be non-negative.

(e.g. Could it be that the `x` values above should all be positive and represent frequencies of observations?)

Comment: Thanks unutbu. Both the feature matrix and the target arrays are numpy arrays. I checked my data and the "feature matrix" has dtype= float64. The target array that contains the target values between (0,1,2,3) is typed as "int64". Ok I may change the dtype of the target array to float but I still get the same problem.

Comment: Hm, sorry then. Can you simplify your data to make the error easily reproducible?

Comment: one column of the feature matrix with 20 rows (numpy float 64):    [-0.23918515 -0.29967287 -0.33007592  0.07383528 -0.09205183 -0.12548226
  0.04770942 -0.54318463 -0.16833203 -0.00332341  0.0179646  -0.0526383
  0.04288736 -0.27427317 -0.16136621 -0.09228812 -0.2255725  -0.03744027
   0.02953499 -0.17387492]
20 rows of the target as int64:[1 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 3 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1]

Comment: I must have misunderstood the usage of chi-square in feature ranking (classification) where there are "features"that are not frequencies and the target are a classes(categories). In my case, it will be dificult to get the frequencies for the features because they are float.

Comment: You can generate frequencies from the data using [numpy.histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html). There is an example/discussion of this [here](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35f.htm).

Comment: In practice, chi2 works as long as the data is non-negative. Use the f-score (``f_classif``) for your data.

Comment: `chi2` is indeed intended for matrices containing frequencies or booleans. `f_classif` runs an ANOVA test, which is appropriate for real-valued (Gaussian) features.